Ignite: Failed to read message. java.io.IOException: Message size must be greater than 0: -1157562108
I'm using Ignite in Kubernetes cluster where I have 1 Client Node (not thin) and 2 Server Nodes in EKS. To connect them, I used KubernetesDiscoverySpi. It works well, but I get some strange WARN/ERROR messages for my Client:
ERROR --- [grid-nio-worker-client-listener-2-#35%ILO-Monitoring%] o.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerProcessor: Failed to read message [msg=o.a.i.i.processors.odbc.ClientMessage@1d634da6, buf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=4 lim=9 cap=65536], ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=2, bytesRcvd=27, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=9, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-2, igniteInstanceName=ILO-Monitoring, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1719715634935, hashCode=819873143, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-2-#35%ILO-Monitoring%]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=23040 cap=23040], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=4 lim=9 cap=65536], inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=o.a.i.i.processors.metric.impl.LongAdderMetric@63a61cb2, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/192.168.27.195:10800, rmtAddr=/192.168.43.202:34812, createTime=1719715634935, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=9, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=9, sndSchedTime=1719715634935, lastSndTime=1719715634935, lastRcvTime=1719715634935, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter, GridNioCodecFilter [parser=ClientListenerNioMessageParser, directMode=true]], accepted=true, markedForClose=false]]]
java.io.IOException: Message size must be greater than 0: -1157562108
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientMessage.readFrom(ClientMessage.java:155)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioMessageParser.decode(ClientListenerNioMessageParser.java:66)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioCodecFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioServer.java:3753)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1379)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2527)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2282)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1911)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

WARN  --- [grid-nio-worker-client-listener-2-#35%ILO-Monitoring%] o.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerProcessor: Client disconnected abruptly due to network connection loss or because the connection was left open on application shutdown. [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Message size must be greater than 0: -1157562108]

ERROR --- [grid-nio-worker-client-listener-3-#36%ILO-Monitoring%] o.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerProcessor: Failed to read message [msg=o.a.i.i.processors.odbc.ClientMessage@55abe76c, buf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=4 lim=9 cap=65536], ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=3, bytesRcvd=27, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=9, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-3, igniteInstanceName=ILO-Monitoring, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1719715638478, hashCode=1139850548, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-3-#36%ILO-Monitoring%]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=23040 cap=23040], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=4 lim=9 cap=65536], inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=o.a.i.i.processors.metric.impl.LongAdderMetric@63a61cb2, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/192.168.27.195:10800, rmtAddr=/192.168.41.114:1984, createTime=1719715638478, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=9, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=9, sndSchedTime=1719715638478, lastSndTime=1719715638478, lastRcvTime=1719715638478, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter, GridNioCodecFilter [parser=ClientListenerNioMessageParser, directMode=true]], accepted=true, markedForClose=false]]]
java.io.IOException: Message size must be greater than 0: -1157562108
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientMessage.readFrom(ClientMessage.java:155)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioMessageParser.decode(ClientListenerNioMessageParser.java:66)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioCodecFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioServer.java:3753)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:175)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$DirectNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1379)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2527)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2282)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1911)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

WARN  --- [grid-nio-worker-client-listener-3-#36%ILO-Monitoring%] o.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerProcessor: Client disconnected abruptly due to network connection loss or because the connection was left open on application shutdown. [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Message size must be greater than 0: -1157562108]

WARN  --- [grid-timeout-worker-#22%ILO-Monitoring%] o.a.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener: Unable to perform handshake within timeout [timeout=10000, remoteAddr=/192.168.43.202:34812]

WARN  --- [grid-timeout-worker-#22%ILO-Monitoring%] o.a.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener: Unable to perform handshake within timeout [timeout=10000, remoteAddr=/192.168.41.114:1984]

As I see it (accoring to remoteAddresses in logs), the first message says that server Node 1 sent a message that can not be processed by the client, so Client disconnect that Server Node, after this the second Server Node did the same.
Worth to say that, there was no usage of cluster at that moment and after those WARN/ERROR messages, cluster is still working (hopefully).
There is also some time range in these logs, the last 2 appeared only after 20s. (I think they mean that Client tried to reconnect to the Cluster)
Can it be a problem with Network for Client Node (I'm using EKS and ClusterIP service as a discovery service)?
How can I troubleshoot it?
Is it critical, or it's just way how Ignite works?
